# Floating Images CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and Bootstrap .
Whenever I try to make a picture stick to left position so I can write text on the right side, I use this Bootstrap class `rounded float-left`
The problem is the image gets over other content in my webpage like the footer.
I know because it's floating .
How can I fix this ? Thank you.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span2">
        <img class="rounded float-left" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3rcu77cYuBPWjgD_I1CLIQ0hoD6iArebYfA&usqp=CAU">
      </div>
      <div class="span10">
        <h2> This is a Course Name </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Why don't you use row and col?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use [the `clearfix` utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/clearfix/), ideally adding it to the `div` that encloses your float (which would be the `div` with the class `span-2` in your code above). This utility class ensures that the floats are cleared properly, and avoids problems like the one you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Try like this please

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span2 clearfix">
        <img class="rounded float-left" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3rcu77cYuBPWjgD_I1CLIQ0hoD6iArebYfA&usqp=CAU">
      </div>
      <div class="span10">
        <h2> This is a Course Name </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you should use the "clearfix" class (under the condition that you use float).
You can achieve what you want by inserting a "clearfix" where appropriate.
I attach an image below. I sincerely hope this helps.
[upload image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUJG2.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

use flexbox or bootstrap grid, or even `<table></table>`

flexbox tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flexbox/index.htm